# pyspark to mongodb connection issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I'm using spark version 3.0 in pyspark and trying to connect with mongodb using below code but it thrown me error

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

working_directory = 'jars/*'

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://username:password@dev-db-recfs.mongodb.net/databasename.data.coll'") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://username:password@dev-db-recfs.mongodb.net/databasename.data.coll'") \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', working_directory) \
    .getOrCreate()

df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
df.printSchema()
```

**Error**

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.load.
> : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
> com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource

Error changed now

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.load.
> : com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
> waiting to connect.

Comment: do you have all necessary jars in the `jars` directory?

Comment: yes i have and now the error has been changed it throws py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.load.
: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect.

Comment: most probably there is no network connectivity to MongoDB

Comment: @AlexOtt atlas azure mongodb instance account , so network should have available

Comment: check access with `nc -vz hostname port`

Comment: @AlexOtt will i try it from ubuntu terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221651/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-alex-ott).